# React custom component - can't set state based on props

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I have to bind a custom datepicker component with internal state:

```
this.state = {
  selectedDate: null,
  dateText: ""
};
```

to a redux-form Field component. The rules are simple - value from outside of my custom component will be passed to it by redux-form with the props:

```
{input: {value: "10-10-2010"} }
```

As you can see, my custom component will not reflect this new value because its internal fields are bound to its state:

```
<TextField
  value={this.state.dateText}
  onChange={this.handleDateInputChange}
/>
```

So I need to somehow set my internal state, based on this prop. This is where problems start:

- If I try to compare the previous vs next Props value within **shouldComponentUpdate** (the intention is to prevent render() if it's just a prop update from parent component) I get very weird issues with TextInput responsiveness - like having to hit backspace twice to delete one character.
- If I try to setState within render(), as well as within other lifecycle hooks it will obviously fail
- If I try to bind the TextField to props.input.value it's not going to work, because "props are for passing values to components"

How can I update the internal state of my component based on the incoming prop, if by 'update internal state' I mean:

- setState, so that the TextField displays the value passed in by the parent component with props
- re-create the internal selectedDate field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `getDerivedStateFromProps`. This method is available in React class components and is static. Here you can update the state of the component according to updated properties. For this also save the last property value inside the state for easy comparison

```
state = {
   propDateText: this.props.dateText,
   dateText: "",
}

getDerivedStateFromProps({ dateText }, { propDateText }) {
  if(propDateText !== dateText) {
     return { dateText, propDateText: dateText }
  }
  return null
}
```

This will compare the last set property `dateText` to the actual one and will replace `dateText` inside the state accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is an interesting option. What's even more interesting is a subsection in the official documentation for this call https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops that said "If you need to perform a side effect (for example, data fetching or an animation) in response to a change in props, use componentDidUpdate lifecycle instead."  And turns out that I can change state from componentDidUpdate without causing recursion!